# Java Web Application with embedded tomcat 7

Tags: java

I want to make a hello java web application with embedded tomcat 7.

I am new. No idea how to start. Can you suggest any useful links. I searched many times but on every link I got a main class in which tomcat is configured.

Any useful links to learn java web application with embedded tomcat 7 from scratch.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/create-a-java-web-application-using-embedded-tomcat

Comment: " java web application with embedded tomcat 7" What does this mean...?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to start with a Java tutorial to understand the terminology and the basic concepts of Java and web applications

The one from <strike>Sun</strike>Oracle is a good start.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html

The continue with the JavaEE tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/

Then you can continue with a tutorial that describes how to create such an application e.g. using the NetBeans IDE:

https://netbeans.org/kb/trails/java-ee.html

Once you have read all that, and started coding, come back with specific questions and code examples that show were your problem is.

You also ant to read the FAQ and help section from Stackoverflow to understand how questions should be asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/help